# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyminizip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python

I was following the installation process for openimis backend -> openimis-be_py, but when I tried installing `pip install -r modules-requirements.txt` I get the following errors below. I have already installed microsoft visual c++ build tools 2022.

```
 Building wheel for pyminizip (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'pyminizip' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyminizip
  Running setup.py clean for pyminizip
Successfully built openimis-be-core openimis-be-individual openimis-be-workflow openimis-be-tasks_management openimis-be-report openimis-be-location openimis-be-medical openimis-be-medical_pricelist openimis-be-product openimis-be-insuree openimis-be-policy openimis-be-contribution openimis-be-payer openimis-be-payment openimis-be-claim openimis-be-claim_batch openimis-be-tools openimis-be-api_fhir_r4 openimis-be-calculation openimis-be-contribution_plan openimis-be-policyholder openimis-be-contract openimis-be-invoice openimis-be-calcrule_contribution_legacy openimis-be-calcrule_third_party_payment openimis-be-calcrule-capitation_payment openimis-be-calcrule_commission openimis-be-calcrule_contribution_income_percentage openimis-be-calcrule_fees openimis-be-calcrule_unconditional_cash_payment openimis-be-im_export openimis-be-dhis2_etl openimis-be-social_protection openimis-be-opensearch_reports openimis-be-payment_cycle openimis-be-calcrule_social_protection openimis-be-payroll
Failed to build pyminizip
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyminizip, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

Comment: I have Microsoft Visual C++ as I mentioned earlier, what is it that am missing? please I need guidance, I have been on this for the past one week

Comment: I have install Microsoft Visual C++ build tools for 2019 and 2022 and still am having the same error, I have lost 2 weeks because of this error. I need a way out of this error.